# Вставить элемент HTML который записан в переменную. JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В переменную массива вписываю все изображение. В консоле по факту проверяю и имею 4 элемента где в каждом несколько своих HTML элементов.

```
var allimg = [];
allimg[allimg.length] = document.getElementById('carouselImg' + 
i).getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Далее в цикле хочу вставить их в тело блока.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  $("#myid").append('<div class="myclass">' + allimg[0][1]+'</div>');
}
```

По факту получаю вот такое в консоле.

```
<div class="myclass">[object HTMLImageElement]</div>
```

Хотя в переменной вроде все правильно записано. В консоле проверяю и там есть массив с изображениями, правда как понял он зубчатый как мне и надо. Как мне вставить в блок изображение с зубчатого массива?

Comment: Конкатегация приводит объект к строке, в данном случает это объект типа HTMLImageElement. Попробуйте сделать элемент из строки `<div class="myclass">` и добавить в него allimg[0][1], и после этого добавить его в `#myid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в allimg сам элемент, а не его HTML код. В этом случае следует сделать так:

```js
let someElement = document.createElement("div");
someElement.innerHTML = "Hi! i'm div!";
someElement.className = "red";

$("#something").append("<div class=\"wrapper\">" + someElement + "</div>"); // так делаете Вы.
$("#something").append("<div class=\"wrapper\">" + someElement.outerHTML + "</div>"); // так нужно делать.
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something">
     Something maybe here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Конкатегация приводит объект к строке, в данном случает это объект типа HTMLImageElement. Попробуйте сделать элемент из строки  и добавить в него allimg[0][1], и после этого добавить его в #myid

```js
let images = $('img')

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let wrap = $('<div class="myclass">')
  wrap.append(images[i])
  $("#myid").append(wrap);
}
```

```css
#myid {
  background: yellow;
}

.myclass {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50">

<div id="myid"></div>
```